# populate pdf fields using php

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to find a sample script that populates a pdf with data using php and none of them work. Would someone have a demo of a working copy? There is no need to post the code of the one scripts I've tried because there is many of them.

here are the scripts i tried: (one of them)

http://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2009/06/19/pdftk-php-officially-released/

Comment: You don't need to post the code of the script you have tried, but you should at least post a link to that script and the accompanying code that you tried to use with it.

Comment: Also please say HOW it doesn't work, just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help much at all.

Comment: they each had different problems, one is the fdf file would load and the pdf would show as corrupted when it wasnt. let me update this post with what i tried give me a minute.